Multiplication of two uint256
How do I compute the multiplication of two uint256 so the result doesn't overflow?
In the end, this multiplication is an intermediate step within a larger operation, in case this extra piece of info helps.
Fyi, I'm not looking to change the order of the operations nor remove any padding.
uint256 a = 10864869065949319007600000000000000000000;
uint256 b = 3300000000000000000000000000000000000000;
uint256 c = 10859952502829164007600000000000000000000;

uint256 result = (a * b) / c;

The overflow occurs in (a * b).
Assembly is more than welcomed if it produces the expected result. Thanks!

One way is to divide them separately by c and then multiply to get the result like result = (((a * 1e18) / c) * ((b * 1e18) / c)) / 1e18. But, you've mentioned that  you're not looking to change the order of the operations, therefore it's not valid in that case.

Yeah, and dividing before multiplying comes with precision loss also, something that I'm trying to avoid @SYEDASADKAZMI

Using https://github.com/SimonSuckut/Solidity_Uint512/blob/main/contracts/Uint512.sol
(uint r0, uint r1) = a.mul256x256(b);
uint result = r0.div512x256(r1, c);


Great. Does it give the accurate result without precision loss ?

Correct. Tested it out already. @SYEDASADKAZMI
